# Why didn't they also rescue the cavemen?

Tags: plot-device, time-trap

In the film Time Trap there are two kind of people trapped in the cave, people from 21st century and then some cavemen that have been living in the cave for ages.

The rescue team that come from distant future takes only first group out of the cave and  leaves the cavemen there.

**Cavemen are human beings too, so why didn't they get rescued?**

Comment: The cavemen seem violent and unpleasant

Comment: Sure but don't you think we would seem violent and unpleasant to a highly developed civilization as well?

Comment: That would be kidnapping. Would you also "rescue" a group of Polynesians from their home on Easter Island, or a group of native Americans living in the Amazon?

Comment: It would be kidnapping, but they look very happy in their new home. I would rescue both Americans and Polynesians if they were trapped in a timeless cave.